# How to pass event (keyCode) to an Object (data load url)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, samsung-smart-tv

I begin to develop for Smart Tv, 
I have already a webapp, and I would like create a little app for smart tv that include my existing webapp.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <!-- TODO : Common API -->
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Widget.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js"></script>
        <!-- TODO : Javascript code -->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/Main.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
        <!-- TODO : Style sheets code -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/stylesheets/Main.css" type="text/css">
        <!-- TODO: Plugins -->
    </head>
    <body onload="Main.onLoad();" onunload="Main.onUnload();" onkeydown="Main.KeyDown();">
    <object type="text/html" data="http://mywebapp.com/" width="1280px" height="720px" style="overflow:auto"></object>
    </body>
</html>
```

work well and page is loaded, but when onkeydown is called, 
I don't arrive to pass the event.KeyCode to my object attribute..

Thank you!

Comment: wouldn't you need to do Main.KeyDown(event.keyCode) ? Looks like you are not passing anything in your onkeydown call.

Comment: thanks for you answer @E.Maggini, KeyDown function work, I view on console log pressed key. But Can't pass this keycode to my attribute object

Comment: what is Main.js? I would expect your integration point would be something in main.js that passes data to your embedded object.